# Check if a set of events occur in a limited time period

Tags: arduino-uno, timers

I am making a project in which I am using 4 Infrared sensors to take an input. The way I want it to work is such that when one of the sensors is triggered, the code listens for input from the other sensors for a fixed amount of time (say 2 seconds). Based on this data, further functions are executed.

I am assigning a number to each of the sensors, and the sequence in which they are triggered is stored in an array like:

```
// All relevant pins of the IR sensors are set to input with names ir1,ir2,ir3,ir4
int sequence[] = {0,0,0,0}
int s1 = digitalRead(ir1); //and similarly for all other pins
int counter = 0; 

if(s1==1){
  sequence[counter] = 1; //similarly 2 for s2 and so on
  counter ++;
}
```

What I am attempting to do is something like this:

```
if(s1 == 1 || s2==1 || s3 == 1 || s4 == 1){
   if(s1 == 1){
      sequence[counter] = 1;
      counter ++;

   //Start listening for other sensors
   } // similarly check which sensor is triggered first

   //Allow 2 seconds for input from all sensors (no input from either one of them is also allowed)
   // After 2 seconds execute some code based on the sequence array which got updated from inputs by different sensors
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Definitely look at the timing principle shown in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some pseudocode that might help:

```
   if millis() - start time >= 2000
         time is up, do what you want with the sequence so far
         maybe a boolean flag here so you only do it once
   if any button is pressed
      if counter == 0
          set start time = millis() // start the timer
          set first in sequence
      else 
          add the button to the sequence
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I put the code to check inputs from the sensors inside a while loop and used the millis() function as the `while` condition. Something like `int a = millis(); int b= millis(); while(a-b <=200){...  a=millis() // updates a at the end of every loop}`